# PERL, Tkx and TeeChart

Tags: teechart

I have a PERL application that has utilized Tkx as the GUI. I would like to possibly incorpoarte interactive graphs into the application and was wondering if anyone had been able to incorporate TeeCharts into such an environment? If so, do you have any examples you might be able to share? Or pointers to documentation and examples?

Thanks in advance.

saxg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what kind of components does Perl support.
But, if Perl supports VCL/ActiveX/NET/Java/PHP/HTML5 components, I don't see why the corresponding TeeChart component shouldn't work with it.